# ColumnPrefixFilter for Hbase scan

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I have an Hbase table with column family's and qualifiers listed below :

```
maindata
content:master:909
content:master:899
content:master:97832
content:master:9902222
content:master:9
.
.
.
content:master:223343453
```

I need to add a filter to Hbase Scan object in my Spark Java class to fetch only the content:master:anynumber columns. Something like :

```
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("content"),Bytes.toBytes("master:[ *[^0-9]. *]"));
```

So that I only get content:master:anynumber columns .
Does Scan support such pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  byte[][] prefixes = new byte[][] {Bytes.toBytes("master:")};
  Filter filter = new MultipleColumnPrefixFilter(prefixes);

  Scan scan = new Scan();
  scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("content"));
  scan.setFilter(filter);
```

Thanks to Hbase `MultipleColumnPrefixFilter`.